# Django Static Files on S3: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to host my Django Static and Media files on Amazon S3 and I've been following every guide out there, but I still end up getting `S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently` errors on deployment of my Elastic Beanstalk Application when it tries to run `collectstatic`.

My S3 is working and I can access other files on it. I also have it set to a custom domain so you can access the same file in the following ways:

1. http://s3.condopilot.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/big/3fca62e2150e8abec3f693a6eae8d2f79bb227fb.jpg
2. https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s3.condopilot.com/thumbs/big/3fca62e2150e8abec3f693a6eae8d2f79bb227fb.jpg
3. http://s3.condopilot.com/thumbs/big/3fca62e2150e8abec3f693a6eae8d2f79bb227fb.jpg

It is the third option that I want to use, but I've tried the other ones aswell. Both with and without `https://` in the settings below.

My settings file look like this

```
#settings.py file
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'
AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
}
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 's3.condopilot.com'
# I have also tried setting AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN to the following:
# - "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/%s/" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
# - "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/%s" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
# - "s3.condopilot.com"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "%s.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False # Tried both True and False
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'http' # Tried with and without

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

The reason I have `AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'` is because without it I get the following error:
`ssl.CertificateError: hostname 's3.condopilot.com.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'`. All advice I find online regarding that error says that `OrdinaryCallingFormat` should be used when bucket name contains dots, example `s3.condopilot.com`.

My custom storages looks like this

```
#custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

And yes, my S3 bucket is set up in **eu-west-1**.

Comment: I run into the exact same issue.  I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: All my buckets are in Northern California region.  But if you created a new bucket whose region is US Standard, bucket name with dots seems to work.  On the other hand, if there's no dot in the bucket name, it would work without setting the calling format.

Answer (score 3):

I think you do not need to set the region S3 in the URL and if you are using **django-storage** replaces this app to **django-storages-redux**. You don't need the custom_storages.py file.

Keep things simple. This is enough.

```
from django.utils import six

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxxXxX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name'
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': six.b('max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (
        AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY))
}

MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL
```